# Checking to see if postGIS is enabled in Ruby on Rails

Tags: postgis, ruby

How can you check if postGIS is enabled in a ruby on rails app? rails seems to do a lot of the backend for you so this is confusing for me. Normally, i would set it up and set up the extension myself.  How can I check that it is enabled?

Answer (score 2):

If you can run arbitrary sql statements

```
SELECT postgis_full_version();
```

will return results if PostGIS is enabled and installed in a schema you have access to.